# Using variable to access define content

Tags: php, variables

This may be impossible, but I was wondering if its possible to output the content of a define using the value of a variable.

Like this:

```
define("SEO_HOME", "Home name");
$var="SEO_HOME";
echo $var
```

This will print off course "SEO_HOME". How can I make it print "Home name" (using the variable $var)?

Edit: Corrected define.

Edit:
My all problem his, the site I'll edit use defines to identify all pages, eg:

```
define("CONTACT_PAGE","Please contact us");
define("INFO_PAGE","Some information about us");
```

And I'll need to add custom html title on those pages, that owner will be able to edit. So I was thinking I would create a DB table with (id, page, title) where page would have CONTACT_PAGE, INFO_PAGE, etc. and title would be the title itself.

Now to make an edit page for site owner, I'll have this:

```
//This would be an while mysql_fetch_assoc and not a multidimentional array, but for example this will work
$titleArray=array(array("CONTACT_PAGE", "my title for contact page"),array("INFO_PAGE", "my title for info page"));
?>
<tr>
    <td>Set title for: <?php echo $titleArray[0][0];?></td> 
    <td><input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $titleArray[0][1];?>" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Set title for: <?php echo $titleArray[1][0];?></td> 
    <td><input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $titleArray[1][1];?>" /></td>
</tr>
```

This shows on first td -> Set title for: CONTACT_PAGE

And I wanted it to show -> Set title for: Please contact us

Hope this clarifies my doubt.

Comment: remove ". $var="seo_home"; should be $var=seo_home;

Comment: imagine value of $var comes from DB, so its a String :) I tried playing around with eval in last 5 minutes, but no luck

Comment: finally you mean you want to put $var in seo_home constant or seo_home into $var ?

Comment: I want to have echo printing:"Home name", the value in define.

Comment: I think i got what you want, see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [constant function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php):

```
 mixed constant ( string $name )
```

> Return the value of the constant indicated by ***name***.
>
> **constant()** is useful if you need to retrieve the value of a constant,
>   but do not know its name. I.e. it is stored in a variable or returned
>   by a function.
>
> This function works also with class constants.

```
<?php
define("SEO_HOME", "Home name");
$var="SEO_HOME";
echo constant($var);
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I wanted :) Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The error with your code is that you swapped the quotes ..

```
 define(seo_home, "Home name")
        ^------------- Quotes Missing 

 $var="seo_home";
      ^---------------  There should be no quotes
```

And also lean to create more readable code by using Upper Case for your constant because they are case sensitive except you enable the case_insensitive option .. [See More Details](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php)

Example :

```
define("SEO_HOME", "Home name");
$var = SEO_HOME;
echo $var;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you do

```
$var=seo_home;
```

when you'll do `echo $var;` will show it, but... you can do `echo seo_home;` and it will show, you don't need a variable.